# Alternate and fast replacement of findViewById in android

Tags: android, android-layout

How I can avoid using `findViewById` in my app. Layout is very complicated and `findViewById` traverses its tree to find view which takes time and it is used several times.

Comment: "How I can avoid using findViewById in my app" -- that is not very practical. "findViewById traverses its tree to find view which takes time" -- and your proof of this is, what, exactly? Please provide a [mcve] showing how you have measured the time and how much time it is taking.

Comment: http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-using-butter-knife-to-inject-views-on-android--cms-23542

Answer (score 18):

First, you must edit your application’s `build.gradle` file and add the following into the android block:

```
android {
    …
    dataBinding.enabled = true
}
```

The next thing is to change the layout file by making the outer tag  instead of whatever ViewGroup you use:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hello"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

The layout tag tells Android Studio that this layout should take the extra processing during compilation time to find all the interesting Views and note them for the next step. All layouts without that outer layout tag will not get the extra processing step, so you can sprinkle these into new projects wherever you like without changing anything in the rest of your application.

The next thing you have to do is to tell it to load your layout file differently at runtime. Because this works all the way back to the Eclair release, there is no reliance on new framework changes to load these preprocessed layout files. Therefore, you do have to make a slight change to your loading procedure.

From an Activity, instead of:

```
setContentView(R.layout.hello_world);
TextView hello = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
hello.setText("Hello World"); // for example, but you'd use resources, right?
```

You load it like this:

```
HelloWorldBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.hello_world);
binding.hello.setText("Hello World"); // you should use resources!
```

Here you can see that a class, `HelloWorldBinding`, was generated for the `hello_world.xml` layout file, and the View with the ID `@+id/hello` was assigned to a final field `hello` that you can use. No casting, no `findViewById`.

It turns out that this mechanism for accessing views is not only much easier than `findViewById`, but can also be faster! The binding process makes a single pass on all Views in the layout to assign the views to the fields. When you run `findViewById`, the view hierarchy is walked each time to find it.

One thing you will see is that it transforms your variable names into camel case (just like `hello_world.xml` becomes the class `HelloWorldBinding`), so if you gave it the ID `@+id/hello_text`, then the field name would be `helloText`.

When you’re inflating your layouts for `RecyclerView`, `ViewPager`, or other things that aren’t setting the Activity contents, you’ll want to use the generated type-safe methods on the generated class. There are several versions that match the `LayoutInflater`, so use the one that is most appropriate for your use. For example:

```
HelloWorldBinding binding = HelloWorldBinding.inflate(
    getLayoutInflater(), container, attachToContainer);
```

If you aren’t attaching the inflated View to the containing `ViewGroup`, you’ll have to get access to the inflated View hierarchy. You can do this from the `getRoot()` method of the binding:

```
linearLayout.addView(binding.getRoot());
```

Comment: Huge shout out for you Simon. This answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: Fantastic walkthrough John. Could perhaps enrich it for handling fragments, menus , it would be perfect then.

Answer (score 5):

Another choice is Kotlin's Android extensions.

```
// Using R.layout.activity_main from the main source set
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MyActivity : Activity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Instead of findView(R.id.textView) as TextView
        textView.setText("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

Comment: Kotlin is supported in android studio 3 ?

Comment: @QasimHasnain It's actually supported even before that. (https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2013/08/working-with-kotlin-in-android-studio/) . But it's bundled in Android Studio 3.0.

Answer (score 4):

you can directly import views from xml:-

add **kotlin extentions** in **app.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

see the below eg.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options, the two main ones being:

Android Data Binding:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

OR

Butterknife:
http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Personally I am a huge fan of Butterknife and use it everywhere where possible, worth noting, this just makes your code nicer to look at. I find that Androids data binding is far more complicated than Butter Knifes (That's more person opinion though...)

To my knowledge you can either use view binding or findViewByID. The clear thing here is that they do the same thing. Data/View binding will just write the findViewByID at compile time.

View Binding just makes your code easier to read. I'm not aware of any changes to android other than soon you will no longer have to cast your findViewByIDs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use viewbinding to replace findviewbyid. It will help you to avoid null pointer exception and type cast exception. You just need to enable view binding in modules gradle file. Then create instance for binding class. then use that instance to reference views in your code.
You will get much clear information from these links.

View binding video tutorial : https://youtu.be/ILUf3Zf0ocI

View binding documentation : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Answer (score 0):

> How I can avoid using findViewById in my app

You can use [getChildAt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt(int)) as alternative for `findViewById` for founding a view inside a **ViewGroup** and its derivative (like **RelativeLayout**, **LinearLayout**, etc). It is super fast because it's only try to find the view from the views array by its index ([link to the source code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java#L6528)):

```
// Child views of this ViewGroup
private View[] mChildren;

// Number of valid children in the mChildren array, the rest should be null or not
// considered as children
private int mChildrenCount;

...

public View getChildAt(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= mChildrenCount) {
        return null;
    }
    return mChildren[index];
}
```

The following is the sample how using `getChildAt`. Assume you have the following Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <TextView/>
   <Button/>
   <EditText/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

you can get all the views with the following:

```
// assume we have inflate the layout
TextView textView = (TextView) getChildAt(0);
Button button = (Button) getChildAt(1);
EditText editText = (EditText) getChildAt(2);
```

But then it is started to become tedious if you have complex layout like the following:

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <TextView/>
   <Button/>

   <LinearLayout>
       <TextView/>
       <Button/>
       <EditText/>
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout>
       <TextView/>
       <Button/>
       <EditText/>
   </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The major problem of using `getChildAt` is you can't easily change your layout position without adapting your code for the change.