# Unresolved reference with the same code Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Studying Kotlin. In tutorial it says I can use:

```
buttonID.setOnClickListener {}
```

without findViewById. But I have unresolved reference. When I open files from tutorial the code works. I copied code (copy-paste from file to file) from tutorial to my project - MainActivity.kt, ActivityMain.xml, but that code also has same error Unresolved reference.

How can it be?

[image]

Comment: kotlinx synthetics are deprecated. Use [viewbinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) instead.

Comment: Make sure that you have added the `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` into your `build.gradle`. Anyway, as @Michael suggested, you should be using view binding.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem a while ago. Make sure you have applied the necessary plugins for the same. More Details - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66787408/12060353